# How to print the alphabet in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

We are trying to design a health care app using Angular. For data filtering we are creating a bar which looks like this below image:

[Data Filterbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwiSo.jpg)

To reduce the line of code we are writing the code in Typescript we are checking in the console whether its displaying  or not.

We are not getting the expected output nor is it showing errors.

Can anyone fix this issue?

```
listIndex(){
while (this.i <= 90) {
    this.alphabets.push(String.fromCharCode(this.i));
}
console.log(this.alphabets());}
```

Output:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

For your reference I'm posting the full TS file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from '../../service/http.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'patienthtml',
    templateUrl: 'app/component/patient/patient.html',
    providers: [HttpService]
})

export class PatientComponent{
constructor( private httpService: HttpService ) {
}
 //simple call init function on controller
i=65;
step = 0;

patientData : any;
alphabets: any = [];

public ngOnInit(): any
{
    this.getPatientData();
}
 getPatientData(){

    this.httpService.getPatients("PatientData").subscribe(
    resp => {    
        if(resp!=null){

            this.patientData=resp.response;
        }
        console.log(this.patientData);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
    );   
}
listIndex(){
    console.log('ReachedHere');
    let alphabets = [];
    for (let i = 65; i <= 90;i++) {
        alphabets.push(String.fromCharCode(this.i));
    }
    console.log(alphabets);

}
getCurrentStep() {
    return this.step;
}
goback(){
    this.step = this.step - 1;    }

toReport(){
    this.step = this.step + 1;    }

}
```

Comment: you forgot to include the image

Comment: You seem to have an infinite loop since `i` is never changed.

Comment: which image are you talking about?

Comment: Anyhow, I don't see what the actual question here is.

Comment: Fix what issue? You haven’t explained what’s wrong or asked a question. Please edit the post and add a description of the problem/error.

Comment: just to print the alphabets using the Typescript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope this helps...

```
let alphabets = [];
for (let i = 65; i <= 90;i++) {
    alphabets.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
console.log(alphabets);
```

Comment: no error is coming but same blank console field is displaying

Comment: i have added the full Ts Code FYI

Comment: @UrstruelyAnanth,  did you use the updated code? it should be `String.fromCharCode(i)`